# Parsing XML backup of a plone site

Tags: xml, plone, zodb

I have the task of parsing a huge backup of a Plone ZODB.
There was no other way to get the backup but in a XML-file which is roughly 433mb big.

Please don't ask why or how, I just got the task of parsing the file in order to retrieve pictures, files and other important data.

I have written a StAX based XML parser in Java and it works so far as I now can read the file, store information and print it into a txt file if necessary.

Now the problem for me is: where is the data I need to retrieve. 
As far as I can read the XML-file (which is pretty difficult even with 16GB of memory), its nodes are all the same, only the attributes differ from another (i. e. "id" and "aka" in the record nodes[of which there are more than 40000]).

Is there any Plone or ZODB Dev who can help and point me into the direction of how and where data is stored in such a XML file? What kind of data do I need to feed to my parser to find, store and print the information.

Or is there any other idea on how I can retrieve the data from the XML file?

Please bear in mind, I >>cannot<< use anything else but this `Plone.xml` as basis.
I also won't be able to share the file for obvious reasons of privacy and security.

Comment: I don't understand, but still.
This file came from a ZMI export of the Plone site in XML format?
About sizes: how can the file be only 433Kb big?

Comment: @keul: I don't know, am just a lower helper. Like I said, don't ask me how and why, I don't know.

Comment: It **could** be that you have a ZMI export in XML format; this is really a deprecated ZODB export format, containing pickles of the object tree. Can you at least show us the tag structure in the file? 433Kb doesn't sound all that big, btw.

Comment: I objected years ago that the XML backup format should have been removed. It's not been supported as long as I've worked with Plone (12 years?). That said, a 433kb file obviously has no blob data, and not much else. I can't see there being much to retrieve.

Comment: You do know that a ZODB database is just a sequential file, right? If you have ANY history of the ZODB you can truncate it (at a reasonable timestamp) to get a valid database.

Comment: Can you please shown an example of XML output?

Comment: @Auspex The XML file does contain documents in form of LaTEX code and pictures in form of Base64 code. Those documents and pictures have to be recovered.
And like I said, I only got the XML file, nothing more, I have no knowledge what-so-ever about ZODB or Plone, never worked directly with it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters & MikkoOhtamaa
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ZopeData>
  <record id="" aka="">
    <pickle>
      <global id="" name="" module=""/>
    </pickle>
    <pickle>
      <dictionary id="">
        <item>
            <key><string id="" encoding=""></string></key>
            <value>
              <list id="">
                  <string id="" encoding=""></string>
                  <string id="" encoding=""></string>
                  <string id="" encoding=""></string>
                  <string id="" encoding=""></string>
.
.
.`

Comment: @HellsBell: Did you remove the content in that snippet of XML to show the structure? That is indeed the Zope XML pickle export, which is an undocumented and long-standing now-unsupported feature of Zope; its entries are generated by [this piece of hind-brain source-code](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Zope/blob/master/src/Shared/DC/xml/ppml.py). The ZODB format is essentially an object tree using pickles, and the XML format tries to represent that in a more readable format. I'll try to document it for you.

Comment: Just a note on context: The XML export has a warning in current versions of the export page noting that it is unsupported. That warning may not have existed on old versions of Plone/Zope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The XML format represents ZODB object entries.

The ZODB uses the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) as the basis for serialising objects to a sequence of bytes. The XML file format tries to give you separate XML tags for the Python primitive types (numbers, strings, containers), but you still get the 'raw' object data, which can contain a lot of entries that are probably not all that interesting for your task.

In the ZODB, a whole object tree is stored; objects containing other objects containing yet more. To prevent any change in this tree requiring a complete rewrite of the stored data, objects can inherit from a dedicated persistence class that tracks changes to just that object separately, and records then use references to those separate records.

The XML format then contains, at the top-level, `<record>` elements; these represent separate objects with attributes in the tree, and if these contain other persistent objects, the references between them are encoded as `<persistent>` elements; looking something like:

```xml
<persistent>
  <tuple>
      <string id="[persistentid.subid]" encoding="base64">[base64-encoded-persistentid]</string>
      <global id="[persistentid.subid]" name="[classname]" module="[module for class]"/>
  </tuple>
</persistent>
```

This then represents a Python tuple with two values; a base64-encoded *persistent ID* (a record reference) and a Python object reference; the latterly can be ignored as the same information is encoded in the referenced `<record>` element.

The *persistent ID* value refers to another record; the simplest way to dereference these is by matching it against the `aka` attribute of a `<record>` tag:

```xml
<record id="[persistentid]" aka="[base64-encoded-persistentid]">
```

The *persistent ID* is really a 8-byte big-endian representation of an unsigned long integer; the `id` attribute represents the same number:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> 'AAAAAAAAAGU='.decode('base64')
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00e'
>>> struct.unpack('>Q', 'AAAAAAAAAGU='.decode('base64'))
(101,)
```

Each `<record>` tag then contains 1 or 2 `<pickle>` tags; the first encoding the object type, the second, if present, the *state* of the object. Without a second record the object is just empty:

```xml
<record id="[persistentid]" aka="[base64-encoded-persistentid]">
  <pickle>
    <global id="[persistentid].1" name="[classname]" module="[module for class]"/>
  </pickle>
  <pickle>
      <!-- ... -->
  </pickle>
</record>
```

What type is used for the state depends on the specific class of the pickled object; the default is to take the class `__dict__` and encode that, but specific implementations can opt to implement a custom [`__getstate__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) (and corresponding `__setstate__`). For the `BTrees` package, for example, you typically will find both key-value pairs *and* `Bucket` objects, which are there just to break up a larger btree into separate records.

Any instances of classes that are not inheriting from the special persistence class (and thus don't get a separate record) are stored as `<object>` tags with the Python class recorded as `<klass>` tag, followed by a tuple for the initial object arguments, plus an optional state.

If you are looking for large binary content (images, files) you **may** be out of luck, as all modern Plone versions use the ZODB BLOB support where such data is stored in separate files. The XML file will merely point to *empty* persistent records where the ZODB blob contents are then found by other means:

```xml
<record id="11545" aka="AAAAAAAALRk=">
  <pickle>
    <global id="11545.1" name="Blob" module="ZODB.blob"/>
  </pickle>
  <pickle>
    <none/>
  </pickle>
</record>
```

The `<none/>` tag represents the Python `None` object (equivalent to `null` in Java). The blob data is then **not** included with the export.

Other random notes:

- `<reference>` tags represent a reference to an object already encoded earlier, but not one that has a separate persistent `<record>`; these point to `[persistentid.subid]` values. There is little point in recording the same object more than once after all.
- The `<unicode>` tag values are encoded with UTF-8; the `encoding` attribute will never be set.
- The `DateTime.DateTime` module has registered a wrapper around an internal [`copy_reg` module function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy_reg.html) used to handle extension types; you'll likely to find entries along the lines of:

  ```xml
  <object id="5406.12">
    <klass>
      <global id="5406.9" name="_dt_reconstructor" module="DateTime.DateTime"/>
    </klass>
    <tuple>
      <global id="5406.10" name="Splitter" module="Products.CMFPlone.UnicodeSplitter.splitter"/>
      <global id="5406.11" name="object" module="__builtin__"/>
      <none/>
    </tuple>
  </object>
  ```

  Here the `_dt_reconstructor` is used to create a new copy of `Products.CMFPlone.UnicodeSplitter.splitter.Splitter` instead; it has no other state (there is no `<state>` tag).

Comment: Wow... sorry for the late answer, was on vacation :/
That is an awesome detailed answer, I will work with it as soon as I can. I would vote if I could, but I cannot yet :/ lot of appreciation mate!!

Comment: Hey! Thanks again for your answer, it basically answered my question, but in the end, it did not solve my problem. We are currently trying to get the data directly out of the ZODB. Thanks again!!

Comment: @HellsBell: a much more sensible approach.